# adding record from one List to another List

Tags: list, flutter

In List One, I am getting some items. Each time those items are changing. Sometimes, I can get more than one record in the List.
In a second List, I would like to store all the data of List One. So, I can then display all the items of List Two.

To make it more clear.

List One = "/temp/file1.jpeg"

List Two = "/temp/file1.jpeg"

List One = "/temp/file2.jpeg"

List Two = "/temp/file1.jpeg,/temp/file2.jpeg"

I have tried this

```
void _openDocumentFileExplorer({fileType: FileType.custom}) async {
    setState(() => _loadingPath = true);

    try{
      _paths = (await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
          type: fileType,
          allowMultiple: true,//_multiPick,
          allowedExtensions: ['pdf']))?.files;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Unsupported operation" + e.toString());
    } catch (ex) {
      print('$ex');
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _loadingPath = false;
      _fileName = _paths != null ?
      _paths!.map((e) => e.name).toString() : '...';
    });
  }

ListView.separated(
                            itemCount:
                            _paths != null && _paths!.isNotEmpty
                                ? _paths!.length
                                : 1,
                            itemBuilder:
                                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              final bool isMultiPath =
                                  _paths != null && _paths!.isNotEmpty;
                              final String name = _paths!
                                  .map((e) => e.name)
                                  .toList()[index];

                              //filesGB store the full path + the file name
                              final filesGB = _paths!
                                  .map((e) => e.path)
                                  .toList()[index]
                                  .toString();

                              print (filesGB);

                              _paths?.addAll(allFiles!.map((e) ));
                              allFiles.addAll(filesGB.toList());
                              allFiles.addAll(filesGB);
                             // allFilesV2.addAll(filesGB);
```

but it does not work. I am getting this error message.
"The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable'"

Please, do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use **SPREAD** **OPERATOR** (...) using a triple dot for merging one array into another.

For example:

```
List list1= ["/temp/file1.jpeg"];

List list2 = [];
```

after some time

```
 list1 = ["/temp/file2.jpeg"];
```

so whenever your list one change do

```
list2 = [...list2,...list1];

print(list2);
```

output: `["/temp/file1.jpeg","/temp/file2.jpeg"]`

I think it would help.

Comment: Thank you. I do not know how to do that. I will try to find how to do it on internet.
With my previous test, I am getting this error message "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<File>'"

Comment: What is the datatype of your list one? 
This error is because you are spreading a String variable which is not possible.
You can spread the list but not the string.

Comment: List<File> filesGB =[];
List<File> allFiles = [];
_paths = (await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
          type: FileType.image,
          allowMultiple: true,//_multiPick,
          ))?.files;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Unsupported operation" + e.toString());
    } catch (ex) {
      print('$ex');}
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _loadingPath = false;
      _fileName = _paths != null ?
      _paths!.map((e) => e.name).toString() : '...';
    });

Comment: If you want to store list of File then     filesGB = _paths.map((e) => File(e)).toList();   whenever filesGB change do allFiles = [...allFiles,...filesGB];  and if you want to join all the element of the allFiles with comma then  String allPaths = allFiles.join(",");  If something else then please explain more detail.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried, but getting an error The argument type 'PlatformFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'
filesGB = _paths!.map((e) => File(e)).toList();
The problem seems to be the ((e)

I am also getting an error with
Image.file(File(filesGB),
The argument type 'List<File>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: Did you declare List<File> filesGB =[]; ?

Comment: Yes. List<File> filesGB =[];
List<File> allFiles = [];
List<String> allFilesV2 = [];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234987/discussion-between-shashank-sahai-and-laurent-thomas).